# How i use configure api to upload a 2gb file in cloud server amazon s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

My main concern is that I have 100 users and they have to upload 2gb file at the same time. So what I use, Currently I am using preassigned URL for uploading files, but I want more convenient way to upload and download files for users?

Comment: It sounds like you already have it working with a presigned URL — could you explain what you would prefer in terms of convenience?

Comment: Yeah, I have to use preassigned URL for uploading, but when I get the download link of the file , It wants me the name of file not give me direct URL. I want that if 100 user upload more than 2gb file can upload and give me a download link of this files

Comment: Try updating the question with a flowchart of what you want to do? It's not clear whether you trying to generate a download link without knowledge of the filename, or if you're trying to restrict the number of users and/or the file sizes or the total bucket size.